# Django fake registrations on the app. Is this hacker activity?

Tags: python, django

We are two people working on a startup based in India. The MVP is not yet complete. So, there is no way for others to know about the website being built and its address.

But the past two days I have observed `fake registrations` on the webApp:

[image]

The other person says he have no Idea. **Is this hacker activity?** If it is,then what am I supposed to do? I don't like to use CAPTCHA. Moreover, I feel this as `hacker activity` because the registrants have not yet confirmed their email address neither did they login since. Please help.

Comment: How is this related to a **specific** programming problem?

Comment: The dates on the last column are signup dates? Those times have a lot of gap between them. So, it seems that someone is doing this manually. In that case a captcha will not mitigate this problem and you needn't worry too much. Just ignore it. If you find the signup times are pretty close, as in seconds, that would mean a script is running. You can then maybe use a captcha, or rate limit the login/signup requests per IP address by configuring your webserver.

Comment: To put things into perspective, this is nothing compared to the bogus requests a webserver gets on a daily basis. If you check your server error logs for 404 requests, you'll see how many requests are made to urls like `/phpmyadmin/`, etc. even if you don't have that. In the access logs, you'll find hundreds of requests with some random, binary characters in the User Agent. And if you're running an email server, I guarantee you that you'll run out of hard disk space if you turn on logging for your email server, that is how many spam requests an email server gets.

Comment: @xyres thanks for the reply. Anyway I have thought about the timegap. No third person knows about the webApp or its use. Just curious.

Comment: @spirit Well, web is an open place. If you haven't told anyone, doesn't mean no one can find out for themselves. Last week I set up a server on AWS. And I didn't even put any website up there. Next day I checked the server logs and it was full of hundreds of spam requests. That's just how the web is. Your case doesn't seem too bad. If you see such sign ups increasing, you may just blacklist these email addresses and domains. But don't let the user know that these emails have been banned. Instead, just tell them an account has been created, so they don't change the email domains.

Comment: Like @KlausD. said, not sure how this relates to a programming problem. But I will say, captcha is a beautiful safety net for this kind of activity. Have you checked out [invisible captcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible)?